# Is there a word with a meaning in between 'desegregate' and 'integrate'?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

[Merriam Webster - Desegregate :](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/desegregate)

> to free of any law, provision, or practice requiring isolation of the members of a particular race in separate units.

[Merriam Webster - Integrate :](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/integrate)

> to form, coordinate, or blend into a functioning or unified whole : unite.

I am interested to find out a word which fits between the above two, and could be used in the following sentence :

Although not segregated, they did not dwell together in unity preferring to be _____________ .

---

This relates to matters of culture, race, ethnic origin, social choices and so on but the best way I can illustrate the concept (and the best way to avoid wandering into controversial issues) is to illustrate the idea with next door's cat.

Next door's cat comes in through my open patio door, nibbles at food which I leave out in the conservatory, sniffs around the kitchen ; then wanders into my bedroom and sleeps for a couple of hours between the suitcases under my bed. Then wanders out again, later.

Doesn't look at me. Doesn't hop up in my lap for a stroke. Very occasionally lets me tickle under his chin.

He has chosen not to integrate with my own occupation of my dwelling. But he does not wish to be segregated.

How should I describe the way in which Pudsey the cat wishes to relate to me ?

Comment: It is a relationship of convenience.

Comment: I'd say that there's a false comparison here. 'Desegregate', from the definition given and in my judgement, implies an imposition (or rather relaxing of constraint) made by a ruling body. But 'integrate' probably most often refers to a non-regulated (from above) process, a natural coming together. // 'Loose association', 'acquaintanceship', and in a less formal register 'nicely spaced' are ballpark terms.

Comment: Is the word *alone* too plain? Separate?

Comment: Would _liberate_ work here? I suspect it only works if the 'integration' is in some way forced rather than natural.

Comment: Recommend "separated", as simply, "Although not segregated, they prefer separation."

Comment: *Solitudinarian* if you're talking about being physically apart.  *Discordant* if they are together but something less than openly hostile.

Comment: Although not segregated, they did not dwell together in unity preferring to be *independent*.

Comment: I was going to offer *independent*, but @Greybeard beat me to it.

Comment: Don't you think before matters of culture, race, ethnic origin, social choices and so on, that relates to vocabulary and writing style?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin No. I do not think so.

Comment: @Nigel Then sorry to be blunt, and it clearly does. If you doubt that, go to Chat and set up a vote.

Comment: @Nigel. Sorry. However disingenuous you'd like to be, why not explain what was difficult? Like it or not, your Question is purely about vocabulary and writing style.

We all see those are both parts of English Language Usage… and I suspect most also see how tenuous that argument is.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Thank you for your comments and your assistance. Much appreciated. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about **unintegrated**? From Cambridge:

> *[integrate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/integrate)*: to mix with and join society or a group of people, often changing to suit their way of life, habits, and customs

Based on this, *integrated* implies mixing with and joining society or a group of people, often changing to suit their way of life, habits, and customs. By the same token, **unintegrated** implies *not* mixing with and joining society or a group of people, often changing to suit their way of life, habits, and customs.

Your example:

> Although not segregated, they did not dwell together in unity preferring to be (remain) **unintegrated**.

One could be *against* segregation -- that is, one could be *for* desegregation -- without being in favor of or engaging in *integration*. Thus speaks Pudsey.

Comment: The simplest answers are always he best. I didn't see it :)